# Dealing cards in java with an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, poker

Essentially what the method specifications entail is thus: remove the specified number of cards from the top of the deck and return them as an array. For example, if the parameter is 4, then the first four cards in the deck will be returned as an array of size 4. Now, I have constructed the method for the most part, but I keep getting an error, and from my understanding is has to do with the passed parameter `numCards`. I'm having a fair bit of difficulty detecting the bug. Any suggestions? Another note, I'm using arrays in this method, but as you can see `cards` is of an ArrayList type. this.cards.toArray(small); is assigning the content of `cards` to the array small. The cards will be removed from the front of the "cards" ArrayList, not the back.

```
public Card[] deal(int numCards) {
        Card[] dealt = new Card[numCards]; 
          for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
           dealt[i] = cards.get(i); 
          }
          Card[] small = new Card[cards.size() - numCards]; 
          for (int i = 0; i < cards.size()-numCards; i++)
          {
           small[i] = this.cards.get(i); 
          }
          this.cards.toArray(small);
          return dealt; 
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Also, when you are calling `cards.get(i)` you are taking from the bottom of the deck, and not the top.

Comment: it's saying on the server that its expecting a value of 4, but gets 45 instead. It's very frustrating as you can probably guess because I feel like I have the method written correctly.

Comment: Can you specify which line is throwing the error?

Comment: oh ok, so what would take it from the top?

Comment: Conveniently enough the server doesn't want to say which line the error is being thrown.

Comment: Please provide declaration and initialization of `cards`

Comment: `cards` is actually already declared within the class as an arraylist, with a size of 45.

Comment: why do you create `small` at all? you are not using it. What is the exact error message?

Comment: to get 4 cards from the top, if your top card has an index 35, you need to start by 31. You are starting from 0. But if your top card has index 0 what you are doing is correct.

Comment: The cards will be removed from the front of the "cards" ArrayList, not the back. the index for the front of the deck is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You won't to take the cards from the top, since you don't know how many you already took, you are take the same all the time. Did you though about taking the cards instead of getting those ?

```
public Card[] deal(int numCards) {
    Card[] dealt = new Card[numCards]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards && !cards.isEmpty() ; i++) { //check for empty deck to prevent Exception
        dealt[i] = cards.remove(0); 
    }
    return dealt;
}
```

This will remove the first cards and put it in the array. I used 0 since the first is removed, so the seconds become the first.

For the `small` array. I don't understand what you want to do since you said **this.cards.toArray(small); is assigning the content of cards to the array small** but you don't do anything with small.